# Is strict positivity preserved by weak convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

If $\{u_n:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}\}$ is a continuous function sequence such that $u_n>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that $u_n$ converges weak to $u \in L^2(\Omega)$. Can I obtain $u>0$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, just take $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $u_n=\frac{1}{n}$.
Then
$$
||u_n-0||_{L^2}^2=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{n^2}dx=\frac{1}{n^2} \to 0
$$
and hence $u_n \to 0$ strongly, and hence weakly, in $L^2$.

Answer (score 6):

Not really. For example, let
$$ u_n=x^n, x\in(0,1) $$
and hence
$$ \|u_n-0\|_2^2=\int_0^1|x^n-0|^2=\frac1{2n+1}\to 0. $$
Namely $u_n$ converges to $0$ strongly in $L^2(0,1)$ and hence weakly to $0$.